# Is this a pattern: stand-alone classes

Tags: architecture, python

Having recently discovered python, I attempted to write a simple logger. Data is read from a device, processes, displayed and stored on disc. Those different tasks belong to different modules, of course.

What appeared to be cool at the time, was to provide command-line interface to each module, as explained here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts

The result is tat although the program as a whole uses `import x` and the uses the classes in the modules, the modules can be used form the command line as well. For example, invoking `hw_comm.py` would open the default device with default options and stream to `stdout`. Also `plot.py` expects data form `stdin` and draws a plot.

I can see a ton of advantages to this design, such as

- easy to debug
- easy to adapt for different use cases
- easy to test
- provides immediate value to the end user, long before the project is finished.

---

I have read only a few thousand lines of python yet, **but haven't seen this approach** (modules as both importable classes and stand-alone scripts) **elsewhere. Why would be that?** Is the extra work to support this format too much for an enterprise project? Or maybe, unlike my tiny project, business scale projects can not easily support this behavior, with hundreds of modules doing different things just to accomplish one complex goal together?

Comment: Python has an interactive interpreter. If I need to use a module interactively I can just use the interpreter. You're not going to get anything remotely complicated done from the command line, where you'll either perform a simple sequence of statements or invent a new language just to do what you can already do from Python.

Comment: @Doval, my impression is that by in/outputting data in form of text tables, other utilities can be used to process the data, e.g. `cut` to get only one column. [Source](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch01s06.html). Doing so from the python interpreter would require typing the code that invokes the class, each time.

Comment: `Doing so from the python interpreter would require typing the code invoking the class, each time.` I'm not sure I see the problem.

Comment: @Doval, let's say the module contains a single fascade class. Let's say that after `if __name__ == "__main__":` there are 10 lines, that use this class in a default way. Now using the module can be as simple as `python hw_comm.py`. If those lines weren't there, one would need to invoke the python interpreter and type those 10 lines. Furthermore, invoking other commands would be more cumbersome than in Bash.

Comment: I still don't see the issue. You could just as easily put those 10 lines in a function. I don't see how you can possibly argue that doing things from inside the same language your code is written in is going to be more cumbersome than using Bash to invoke a script that parses strings that eventually leads to some code being run.

Answer (score 2):

The benefits of being able to execute a module from the command line are clear, as you outline.

However, what are the benefits of this functionality lying *in the module itself?*    That is not so clear.  You could easily accomplish the same thing with a simple wrapper script that called the module.  This would be no more work to code and just as convenient to use.

And, in my mind, it is better to logically separate the module from code that uses the module.

Answer (score 0):

Using an `if __name__ == "__main__"` block to run a few quick tests is not unusual - you can even find it [in the standard library](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/72a91df86b07/Lib/heapq.py#l464).

However, if you intend to distribute your package as a command-line app, users generally expect there to be one entry point to the executable. (Imagine how hard `rm` would be to use if, instead of adding a `-r` flag to recurse directories, you had to type `rmdir`, a completely different command).

In Python-land we generally achieve this using a single `main` script which imports the package's internal modules and calls different functions as required.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't see this more often is that having a file be both a module and a script doesn't work well except in simple cases.  The primary reason is that as a system get more complex you end up with more modules, and at some point the `__main__` script will get imported, and at that point you then have two copies of that module in memory -- once as `sys.modules['__main__']` and once as `sys.modules[actual_name]`.  At that point weird errors start happening and if you don't know what's going on you can lose hours figuring it out.